# How to increment number of rows in .csv

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv

I am doing a iPhone application in Xcode 5 where I read a list of president names from a .csv file. I also read other info such as party and date from-to in office from the file.

I then display the names in a TableViewController, and when the user clicks on a name, they see that presidents details in a UIViewController.

I want to however, do something as follows. Imagine there is a UIViewController before the TableViewController, where the user can select to only view e.g. the Democratic presidents, I then need to loop through the .csv file and only read these from the .csv and display them on the TableViewController.

I have tried a for loop on my array of rows of presidents, but it simply keeps iterating over the first row (ie. the first president in the .csv file).

Here is what I tried. Firstly, the viewDidLoad to read in from the .csv file (it can be assumed that this is working as intended as I have tested this).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *outError = nil;
    NSString *fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"USPresidents"  ofType:@"csv"];

    NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&outError];
    self.importedRows = [self csvArray2PresidentsArray:[fileString csvRows]];

    // Prints a list of all the presidents - working as intended
    NSLog(@"Filestring: %@", fileString);
}
```

And in my cellForRowAtIndexPath I tried:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    President *p = (President *)[self.importedRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.importedRows.count; i++)
    {
        if ([p.party isEqualToString:@"Democratic-Republican"])
        {
            NSLog(@"President Name: %@ , President Party: %@", p.name, p.party);
            NSString *tempString;
            tempString = p.party;
            NSLog(@"TempString: %@", tempString);
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempString]; 
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But like I said, when I add a break point to cellForRowAtIndexPath, the for() loop simply keeps repeating over the first row of: 
    self.importedRows.count

Can anyone please tell me how to increment the rows so that I can traverse all the rows in the .csv file one after the other to pick out the correct values to display on the TaleViewContoller?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot filter or restrict the table view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

You should create a filtered array `self.filteredRows` that contains only the objects that you want to display (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`). Then use `self.filteredRows` instead of
`self.importedRows` in all table view data source methods.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're only seeing the first row in the loop is that the row being examined (President *p) is initialized before the loop begins.

See how the variable "i" is never mentioned inside the for loop body?  That's the only thing that can change in the loop.

The right answer is to take MartinR's advice (he's wrong that you cannot filter in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but right that it's a terrible idea).

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *presidents;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *party;

- (void)setParty:(NSString *)party {
    _party = party;
    _presidents = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSArray *)presidents {
    if (!_presidents) {
        NSPredicate *partyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(President *president, NSDictionary *bind) {
            return [president.party isEqualToString:self.party];
        }];
        _presidents = [self.importedRows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:partyPredicate];
    }
    return _presidents;
}
```

Now, whenever the UI sets `self.party = @"Whig";`, the table will get updated. Have numberOfRowsInSection answer `self.presidents.count` and in cellForRowAtIndex path, configure the cell with `self.presidents[indexPath.row]`.